TYPO3 v12 Backend Mixed Content Error loading Javascript Libs
We have setup TYPO3 behind a TRAEFIK Reverse Proxy. Yesterday everything looks good, but today our Backend is empty. In the Browser Console we found

"Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but
requested an insecure script ''. This request has been blocked;
the content must be served over HTTPS."

And after that the following errors:

'TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module:
https://example.com/typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Public/JavaScript/live-search/result-types/page-result-type.js?bust=c8eb9eafbb5af2f5c1b1dbbd651572846060258b'

Why TYPO3 is trying to load a Script with an insecure URL?
Our Website seems to be good. But Login into Backend ends up with the left Menu und a white Screen:
    <?php
return [
    'BE' => [
        'debug' => false,
        'disable_exec_function' => 0,
        'installToolPassword' => '*****',
        'lockSSL' => 0,
        'loginRateLimit' => 3,
        'loginRateLimitInterval' => '5 minutes',
        'loginRateLimitIpExcludeList' => '*****',
        'passwordHashing' => [
            'className' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Crypto\\PasswordHashing\\Argon2idPasswordHash',
            'options' => [],
        ],
        'sessionTimeout' => 28800,
        'showRefreshLoginPopup' => true,
        'versionNumberInFilename' => '0',
        'warning_email_addr' => '*****',
        'warning_mode' => 0,
    ],
    'DB' => [
        'Connections' => [
            'Default' => [
                'charset' => 'utf8',
                'dbname' => '*****',
                'driver' => 'mysqli',
                'host' => 'database',
                'password' => '*****',
                'port' => 3306,
                'user' => '*****',
            ],
        ],
        'extTablesDefinitionScript' => 'extTables.php',
    ],
    'EXT' => [],
    'EXTENSIONS' => [
        'backend' => [
            'backendFavicon' => '',
            'backendLogo' => '',
            'loginBackgroundImage' => '',
            'loginFootnote' => '© 2024 ******',
            'loginHighlightColor' => '',
            'loginLogo' => 'EXT:******/Resources/Public/Images/mbFavicon.svg',
            'loginLogoAlt' => '******',
        ],
        'extensionmanager' => [
            'automaticInstallation' => '0',
            'offlineMode' => '0',
        ],
        'flux' => [
            'autoload' => '1',
            'debugMode' => '0',
            'doktypes' => '0,1,4',
            'flexFormToIrre' => '0',
            'handleErrors' => '0',
            'pageIntegration' => '1',
            'plugAndPlay' => '0',
            'plugAndPlayDirectory' => 'design',
        ],
        'indexed_search' => [
            'catdoc' => '/usr/bin/',
            'debugMode' => '0',
            'deleteFromIndexAfterEditing' => '1',
            'disableFrontendIndexing' => '0',
            'enableMetaphoneSearch' => '1',
            'flagBitMask' => '192',
            'fullTextDataLength' => '0',
            'ignoreExtensions' => '',
            'indexExternalURLs' => '0',
            'maxAge' => '0',
            'maxExternalFiles' => '5',
            'minAge' => '24',
            'pdf_mode' => '20',
            'pdftools' => '/usr/bin/',
            'ppthtml' => '/usr/bin/',
            'unrtf' => '/usr/bin/',
            'unzip' => '/usr/bin/',
            'useMysqlFulltext' => '0',
            'xlhtml' => '/usr/bin/',
        ],
        'powermail' => [
            'disableBackendModule' => '0',
            'disableIpLog' => '1',
            'disableMarketingInformation' => '0',
            'disablePluginInformation' => '0',
            'disablePluginInformationMailPreview' => '0',
            'enableCaching' => '0',
            'replaceIrreWithElementBrowser' => '0',
        ],
        'save_and_close' => [
            'saveAndClose' => '1',
            'saveAndView' => '1',
        ],
        'scheduler' => [
            'maxLifetime' => '1440',
        ],
        'static_info_tables' => [
            'enableManager' => '0',
        ],
        'vhs' => [
            'disableAssetHandling' => '0',
        ],
        'videos' => [
            'controls' => '1',
        ],
        'ws_t3bootstrap' => [
            'tidy' => '0',
        ],
    ],
    'FE' => [
        'compressionLevel' => 0,
        'debug' => false,
        'loginRateLimit' => 3,
        'loginRateLimitInterval' => '5 minutes',
        'loginRateLimitIpExcludeList' => '******',
        'passwordHashing' => [
            'className' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Crypto\\PasswordHashing\\Argon2idPasswordHash',
            'options' => [],
        ],
    ],
    'GFX' => [
        'gdlib_png' => 1,
        'jpg_quality' => '86',
        'processor' => 'GraphicsMagick',
        'processor_allowTemporaryMasksAsPng' => false,
        'processor_colorspace' => 'RGB',
        'processor_effects' => false,
        'processor_enabled' => true,
        'processor_path' => '/usr/bin/',
    ],
    'INSTALL' => [],
    'LOG' => [
        'TYPO3' => [
            'CMS' => [
                'deprecations' => [
                    'writerConfiguration' => [
                        'notice' => [
                            'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Log\Writer\FileWriter' => [
                                'disabled' => true,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'MAIL' => [
        'defaultMailFromAddress' => 'no-reply@******',
        'defaultMailFromName' => '******',
        'transport' => 'smtp',
        'transport_sendmail_command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i ',
        'transport_smtp_encrypt' => false,
        'transport_smtp_password' => '',
        'transport_smtp_server' => '******',
        'transport_smtp_username' => '',
    ],
    'SYS' => [
        'UTF8filesystem' => true,
        'belogErrorReporting' => 0,
        'caching' => [
            'cacheConfigurations' => [
                'autoloader' => [
                    'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\SimpleFileBackend',
                    'frontend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Frontend\\PhpFrontend',
                    'groups' => [
                        'system',
                    ],
                    'options' => [
                        'defaultLifetime' => 0,
                    ],
                ],
                'extbase_object' => [
                    'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\ApcuBackend',
                    'frontend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Frontend\\VariableFrontend',
                    'groups' => [
                        'system',
                    ],
                    'options' => [
                        'defaultLifetime' => 0,
                    ],
                ],
                'hash' => [
                    'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                ],
                'imagesizes' => [
                    'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                    'options' => [
                        'compression' => true,
                    ],
                ],
                'pages' => [
                    'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                    'options' => [
                        'compression' => true,
                    ],
                ],
                'rootline' => [
                    'backend' => 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Backend\\Typo3DatabaseBackend',
                    'options' => [
                        'compression' => true,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'ddmmyy' => 'd.m.Y',
        'devIPmask' => '*',
        'displayErrors' => 0,
        'encryptionKey' => '******',
        'exceptionalErrors' => 12290,
        'features' => [
            'security.backend.htmlSanitizeRte' => true,
            'security.usePasswordPolicyForFrontendUsers' => true,
        ],
        'phpTimeZone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
        'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'first',
        'reverseProxyIP' => '172.18.0.*,172.20.0.*',
        'reverseProxySSL' => '*',
        'sitename' => '******',
        'systemLocale' => 'de_DE.utf8',
        'systemMaintainers' => [
            5,
        ],
        'trustedHostsPattern' => '.*',
    ],
];


TYPO3 does what it is told - or not told ;-)
If you are running TYPO3 behind a reverse proxy, then you must have told TYPO3 about it, right?
That sounds a lot like a missing IP in $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SYS']['reverseProxySSL'].
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/Configuration/Typo3ConfVars/SYS.html#confval-globals-typo3-conf-vars-sys-reverseproxyssl

My TRAEFIK Container has 172.18.0.2, the TYPO3 Container runs at 172.18.0.4.
Our $GLOBALS Entries in 'SYS' Section looks like this:
'reverseProxyHeaderMultiValue' => 'first',
'reverseProxyIP' => '172.18.0.,172.20.0.',
'reverseProxySSL' => '*',
Maybe another Idea?

That should work... Have you already tried to use the concrete (single) IPs? The requested (insecure) files are part of the core, not some custom/extensions JS, right?

After deleting the DCE Extension and cache clearing it seems to work. But after one day the same problem comes back. First error occurs when loading
`Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
main:1  Mixed Content: The page at 'https:///typo3/main?token=yy' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http:///typo3/sysext/core/Resources/Public/JavaScript/Contrib/lit/?bust=xx'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Sounds very strange. And Armin should actually know what he's doing in DCE... IMO v3.2.0 of DCE was released in the last few days. Maybe that's worth a try. (Please add the TYPO3 version in the thread, it might help)

I dont think that DCE ist the reason for our problems. Now we have changed our dce content to default content elements, so we dont need it anymore.
